# How do I retrieve the struts2-junit-plugin without using Maven?

Tags: plugins, junit, struts

I've googled on it and I've seen a lot of different sites that offers the struts2-junit-plugin.

I'm currently using struts-2.2.1.1. Should I get struts2-junit-plugin-2.2.1.1 as well?

Also, my project doesn't use Maven. When I downloaded a struts2-junit-plugin, I inspected the .jar file and found a pom.xml containing all of its dependencies. Should I separately download all these dependencies manually since I don't use Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you should use the matching junit-plugin version (2.2.1.1)
2. Yes, but you *also* need to load the dependencies' dependencies, the dependencies' dependencies' dependencies ad nauseam until you're at the end.

Point 2 is why you *really* should be using Maven or similar mechanism.

Getting dependencies by hand is error-prone, tedious, and silly.